What is meant by "songs in the night" in Job 35?
We read in Job 35:9-10 (KJV):

By reason of the multitude of oppressions they make the oppressed to cry: they cry out by reason of the arm of the mighty. But none saith, Where is God my maker, who giveth songs in the night;

There are certain birds that sing during the night. Is that meant here, or is the usage of "songs in the night" a metaphor for something else?
My question is: What is meant by "songs in the night"?

The birds are not a metaphor but their singing at night is a metaphor for for God's justice, which - according to Elihu - must not be questioned. This is part of Elihu's attempt to denigrate Job's declaration that he has been treated unfairly. Elihu denounces Job's complaint as vain, ignorant and wicked. God will not answer Job when he dares to question Him in this way. Reading the verse in context clarifies this, especially when considering the overall tenor of the dialog:

10 But none saith, 'Where is God my maker, who giveth songs in the
night;
11 Who teacheth us more than the beasts of the earth, and maketh us
wiser than the fowls of heaven?'
12 There they cry, but none giveth answer, because of the pride of
evil men.
13 Surely God will not hear vanity, neither will the Almighty regard
it....
16 Therefore doth Job open his mouth in vain; he multiplieth words
without knowledge.

In the end Elihu is proven wrong. God does answer Job. Then, in vs. 42:7 God rejects the attacks on Job's integrity and sides with Job, saying it is he (not his friends) who has spoken the the truth about God. Like Jacob, Job wrestles with God, while Elihu says the difficult questions should not be asked. At the end of the day it was Elihu, not Job, who was "multiplying words without knowledge." As to which species of bird Elihu refers to, any bird that calls at night will do.

The argument presented Elihu bears a resemblance to David's Psalm 32.

3 When I kept silent,
my bones wasted away
through my groaning all day long.
4 For day and night
your hand was heavy on me;
my strength was sapped
as in the heat of summer.
5 Then I acknowledged my sin to you
and did not cover up my iniquity.
I said, “I will confess
my transgressions to the Lord.”
And you forgave
the guilt of my sin.
6 Therefore let all the faithful pray to you
while you may be found;
surely the rising of the mighty waters
will not reach them.
7 You are my hiding place;
you will protect me from trouble
and surround me with songs of deliverance.

In Job 35:9, Elihu rebukes Job, suggesting that Job's appeal to the Lord aims more from a desire for relief from his suffering than from genuine faith. This is the reason Job does not receive a direct response from the Lord. Elihu asserts that the Lord Almighty can certainly deliver people from their darkness, granting them a peace that allows them to sing even in their deepest moments of despair.
This lesson finds resonance in the experience of Paul and Silas. In Acts 16:25, Paul and Silas were imprisoned. Despite in this dreadful moments, at midnight, Paul and Silas were praying and singing hymns to God. Suddenly, an earthquake shook the prison and the doors flew opened.
The imagery of "Song in the night" symbolizes the peace of mind that comes to those who wholeheartedly entrust themselves to the Lord, even amid adversity.

Short Answer: “songs in the night” is metaphorical. It does not refer to literal birds singing at night, but rather to a deeper, spiritual concept.
The phrase “songs in the night” is often interpreted as God providing comfort, hope, and joy during times of darkness, distress, and/or suffering.
For example, note this from The Great Texts of the Bible, James Hastings:

God is the giver of the song. No man can make a song in the night
himself; he may attempt it, but he will find how difficult it is. It
is not natural to sing in trouble, “Bless the Lord, O my soul, and all
that is within me bless his holy name”; for that is a daylight song.
But it was a Divine song which Habakkuk sang when in the night he
said, “Although the fig-tree shall not blossom,” and so on, “yet I
will rejoice in the Lord, I will joy in the God of my salvation.”
Methinks, on the margin of the Red Sea, any man could have made a song
like that of Moses, “The horse and his rider hath he thrown into the
sea”; the difficulty would have been to compose a song before the Red
Sea had been divided, and to sing it before Pharaoh’s hosts had been
drowned, while yet the darkness of doubt and fear was resting on
Israel’s hosts. Songs in the night come only from God; they are not in
the power of man.

Also, Barry J. York wrote in Tabletalk Magazine,

As we look at Scripture, one conclusion is apparent. They should sing.
For the biblical testimony is that God provides “songs in the
night”—lyrics to bring to Him in times of great heart distress.

We see something beautiful in the example of Jesus. Barry continues:

When Jesus entered the dark night of His soul on Calvary’s cross, He
had these same songs on His heart. He quoted from the Psalms,
expressing both His despair in the words, “My God, my God, why have
you forsaken me?” (Ps. 22:1), and His hope when He finally said, “Into
your hand I commit my spirit” (Ps. 31:5). Friend, if your Lord needed
these words at His blackest hour, so do you. When you do not know what
to say or pray, when you have groaning too deep for words, when the
darkness falls, then turn to the songs in the night the Lord Himself
used, and that He still provides for you.

I would like to note that night often signifies sin, ignorance, calamity, affliction and suffering:
Barnes' Notes what night often signifies,

Night, in the Scriptures, is an emblem of sin, ignorance, and
calamity. Here "calamity" is particularly referred to; and the idea
is, that God can give joy, or impart consolation, in the darkest
season of trial. He can impart such views of himself and his
government as to cause the afflicted even to rejoice in his dealings;
he can raise the song of praise even when all external things are
gloomy and sad

From The Great Texts of the Bible, James Hastings:

It is evident that “night” is here used as a symbol of affliction and
suffering


There is an untold relief in light. Whilst suffering and sorrow
continue just the same, light seems to reanimate hope and endurance.
Darkness has the opposite effect. The greatest inward conflicts take
place during its long hours—sickness is doubly weary, and full of
uneasiness. The unclosed eye, the unsubdued pain, the voice of
sympathy hushed—all these tax often to the uttermost the patience of a
Christian.

The songs in the night show that human happiness depends on our relation to God. Even in the face of adversity, true success and happiness lie in being honest, meek, merciful, and pure in heart.
So, in essence, “songs in the night” symbolizes the comfort, the hope, and the joy that God provides in times of distress and hardship. It’s a beautiful metaphor about the enduring faith of the human spirit in the face of adversity.
Let me end with this quote:

The midnight song is a powerful witness in favour of our religion.
There are times when the heart has to fill the place of the eye. We
see nothing; the sky is dark; yet we are not dismayed. There is no ray
of light upon our path that we can discern, no opening in the cloud,
no rent in the gloom. Yet somehow the heart sings—sings in the shadow,
sings in the silence. And at these times we are to take the song as
the substitute for the sun.


The "Songs in the Night" of Job 35:10 is a reference to the saved who trust the Almighty and are able to sing songs of joy in the midst of calamity.  Note the Pulpit commentary:

God is one who giveth songs in the night. The truly pious man sings
hymns of praise in his affliction, as Paul and Silas did in the jail
at Philippi, looking to God with faith and a lively hope for
deliverance. Job 35:10

The Jews often sang songs of joy and deliverance, Ps 42:8; 149:5; Ac 16:25, which is best illustrated by the example of Paul and Silas -

About midnight Paul and Silas were praying and singing hymns to God,
and the other prisoners were listening to them.

